# Text input is cleared right after focus moves away in Playwright Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, playwright, playwright-python

I have a text input field which is present on a popup window that requires a 6-digit text input in string format. It seems that there's a background check to verify whether the input is a 6-digit number. When I manually enter the text and press the Tab key, the text is retained. However, when I attempt to simulate the same using Playwright, the text input field is cleared right after entering the text and pressing Tab

My code looks something like this.

```
pin = str("123456")

page.type('input[type="text"]', pin)
page.wait_for_load_state("load")

page.keyboard.press("Tab")
page.wait_for_load_state("load")
```

**More Info:**
It gives an error in popup screen saying `ORA-01422 : exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows` after clicking tab key for a fraction of second and dissapear instantly. which is not visible to normal eye. I caught the same using screen recorder and playing frame by frame. I am attaching screenshot of the same.

[image: ORA-01422 : exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows]

**What I've Tried:**

Ensured that the pin variable is a string.
Used page.wait_for_load_state("load") to wait for the page to load after entering the text and pressing Tab.
Checked for any JavaScript events or validations triggered by the Tab key. It validates whether the pin is six digit or not. Tor that
I have Used page.wait_for_load_state("load"). Also used different browsers like chrome, chromium and Nighty.

**Expected Result:**
I expected the text entered into the input field to be retained after pressing Tab, similar to the manual interaction.

**Actual Result:**
The text input field is cleared after entering the text and pressing Tab when using Playwright.

**Request for Assistance:**
I'm seeking guidance on resolving this issue. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has suggestions on how to troubleshoot and solve this, your input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using Playwright's sync_api (otherwise you should be using `await` before each async call).

First of all, I'd like to point out that `page.type`, and `page.keyboard.press` are old Puppeteer style methods, for which Playwright has developed better alternatives. To work with elements, please use `Locator` objects instead, it will lazily resolve the element on every action, avoiding things like stale element errors, and with having strict matching built-in. Here's a guide to Locators:
https://playwright.dev/python/docs/locators

Next, I am assuming that when you type something and press TAB, you are staying on the same page. The page you were already navigated to. In that case, `page.wait_for_load_state` is not doing anything, since:

> If current document has already reached the required state, resolves immediately.

(Taken from https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-load-state)

With single-page applications, where parts of the page are dynamically loading/reloading based on REST API calls, made in the background, waiting for a load state is no guarantee at all that the page will be ready to interact with. Most of the time though, you don't need to explicitly wait on anything, before doing actions, because Playwright's auto-waiting (actionability checks) make sure an element exists in the DOM, is visible, is enabled, is stable (no animations still going on), is not covered by some glass pane, etc.:
https://playwright.dev/python/docs/actionability

Unfortunately, there are cases where you do have to wait for something explicitly, because pages often don't care to disable or hide elements, or show a glass pane in front, while a page is loading/waiting for some background API call. (This is really a usability issue in the pages, which even would be experienced by users with a slow internet connection. Some such usability issues will be revealed by using Slow 3G network throttling in Chrome Developer tools.)

Long story short: I think you start to type before the page initialization has finished (page is not fully 'hydrated' yet). So after typing and leaving the field, the field will be initialized with an empty value, overwriting what you 'typed' before.
To avoid this, try to find some indicator of the page being ready to handle input. For example, the last thing that might happen, while initializing a login page, is setting the focus on the userName field.
In such case, you could wait for:

```
focusedUserName = page.locator('#userName:focus')
focusedUserName.wait_for()
```

In other cases, there is always some REST API call which is done last, before the page is ready. In such case, you could wait for the response, like:

```
with page.expect_response('https://the_last_expected_rest_api_response') as response_info:
    page.goto('https://the_pin_page')

pin = '123456'
pinField = page.locator('input[type="text"]');
pinField.fill(pin);
pinField.press('Tab');
```

It depends on the page, which indication of page readiness you can use. And all of this is really a workaround. The best solution is to work with the frontend developer of the app to make the page not 'look ready' to the user and to Playwright's actionability checks when it's not ready.

Comment: I followed the methods as you suggested. I used `locator` object instead of `page` method.  I tested my code using python interpreter. It is perfectly locating and clicking in text input field. Also retaining text. But when I run it in vs code it not even detecting `locators`.